# How to solve AttributeError in python active_directory?

Tags: python-2.7, active-directory, runtime-error

Running the below script works for 60% of the entries from the MasterGroupList however suddenly fails with the below error. although my questions seem to be poor ou guys have been able to help me before. Any idea how I can avoid getting this error? or what is trhoughing off the script? The masterGroupList looks like:

Groups Pulled from AD

SET00 POWERUSER

SET00 USERS

SEF00 CREATORS

SEF00 USERS

...another 300 entries...

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ks185278\OneDrive - NCR Corporation\Active Directory Access Scr
ipt\test.py", line 44, in <module>
    print group.member
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\active_directory.py", line 805, in __getat
tr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

Code:

```
from active_directory import *
import os

file = open("C:\Users\NAME\Active Directory Access Script\MasterGroupList.txt", "r")
fileAsList = file.readlines()
indexOfTitle = fileAsList.index("Groups Pulled from AD\n")
i = indexOfTitle + 1
while i <= len(fileAsList):
    fileLocation = 'C:\\AD Access\\%s\\%s.txt' % (fileAsList[i][:5], fileAsList[i][:fileAsList[i].find("\n")])
    #Creates the dir if it does not exist already
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(fileLocation)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fileLocation))
    fileGroup = open(fileLocation, "w+")    
    #writes group members to the open file
    group = find_group(fileAsList[i][:fileAsList[i].find("\n")])
    print group.member
    for group_member in group.member: #this is line 44
        fileGroup.write(group_member.cn + "\n")
    fileGroup.close()
    i+=1
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of `find_group`

Comment: it is part of the [active_directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/active_directory.html) module. It searches for a group in the AD by the name provided in the ()

Comment: @th3an0maly I really think it has to do with the line I labeled "this is line 44" or how the active_directory module works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know python, but I know Active Directory fairly well.

If it's failing on this:

```
for group_member in group.member:
```

It could possibly mean that the group has no members.

Depending on how phython handles this, it could also mean that the group has only one member and `group.member` is a plain string rather than an array.

What does `print group.member` show?

The source code of active_directory.py is here: https://github.com/tjguk/active_directory/blob/master/active_directory.py

These are the relevant lines:

```
    if name not in self._delegate_map:
        try:
            attr = getattr(self.com_object, name)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                attr = self.com_object.Get(name)
            except:
                raise AttributeError
```

So it looks like it just can't find the attribute you're looking up, which in this case looks like the 'member' attribute.

Comment: The last thing returned by printing group.member is the AD path for the members of the last group it does before it breaks. Although I do know the next group that it should be processing has no members so that is plausible. 
Looking at the AD module it looks like the section of code where it is returning the Attribute Error is trying to get the properties for the of an object.

Comment: Added the source code for active_directory.py to my answer.

Comment: With further testing it appears that you are 100% correct that is the only empty group and it is the only problem group. Now to figure out how to manipulate python to check if the group is empty before trying to execute that code. Do you know if there is a specific was AD signifies this?

Comment: I know that .NET has a .Contains() method to check. I poked through that python source code, but I did not find an equivalent. So I guess you'll just have to catch the AttributeError.

Comment: For conclusiveness the solution I went with was to have the code ignore the error using try, except and pass, since I knew the source and that it was irrelevant to the function of my code.
       
        `try:
  print group.member
  for group_member in group.member:
   fileGroup.write(group_member.cn + "\n")
 except AttributeError: 
  pass`